# Coq tactic to sort a list?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

For a proof, I want to use the fact that for any list of integers, there exists a sorted version of that list. This seems obvious to me, but I couldn't find a tactic that does something like that. I tried to create my own (below), but I got stuck, so maybe this fact isn't as obvious as I thought it was (or maybe it isn't even true?)

```
Definition sorted := (StronglySorted (λ x y, x ≤ y)).
Lemma exists_sorted:  ∀ (L : list Z) (a : Z), ∃ L0 : list Z, sorted L0 ∧ (List.In a L ⇔ List.In a L0).
Proof.
  induction L.
  - intros.
    exists nil.
    split.
    + apply SSorted_nil.
    + tauto.
  - intros.
    pose proof (IHL a).
    destruct H as [L0 [H H0]].
```

and from there my idea seems a bit circular. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Summary:

```
Require Import Orders Sorting ZArith.

Module ZOrder <: TotalLeBool.
Definition t := Z.
Definition leb := Z.leb.
Lemma leb_total : forall x y : t, leb x y = true \/ leb y x = true.
Proof.
intros x y; case (Zle_bool_total x y); auto.
Qed.

End ZOrder.

Module ZSort := Sort ZOrder.

Lemma Transitive_Zle_bool : Transitive (fun x y => is_true (x <=? y)%Z).
Proof.
intros x y z; unfold is_true; rewrite <- 3!Zle_is_le_bool; apply Z.le_trans.
Qed.

Lemma exists_sorted:  forall (L : list Z), exists L0 : list Z, 
 StronglySorted (fun x y => is_true (x <=? y)%Z) L0 /\ 
 (forall a: Z, List.In a L <-> List.In a L0).
Proof.
intros l; exists (ZSort.sort l).
split;[apply ZSort.StronglySorted_sort; apply Transitive_Zle_bool | ].
intros a; split; apply Permutation.Permutation_in.
  apply ZSort.Permuted_sort.
apply Permutation.Permutation_sym; apply ZSort.Permuted_sort.
Qed.
```

This is a matter of navigating the Coq libraries.  I don't know how you came by the concept `StronglySorted`, but it is indeed present in the libraries shipped with the Coq system.

If you only type the following

```
Require Import Sorted ZArith.
```

Then you only get a definition of what it means for a list to be sorted, but not the definition of a sorting function.  You see this because the command

```
Search StronglySorted.
```

only returns half a dozen theorems that are mostly linked with the relation between `StronglySorted` and `Sorted` and the induction principle for `StronglySorted`.

By using `git grep` on the sources of the Coq distribution, I figured out that the concept `StronglySorted` was used in two libraries, the second one is named `Mergesort`.  Aha!  *merge sort* is the name of an algorithm, so it will probably constructed a sorted list
for us.  Now both `Mergesort` `Sorted` are included in `Sorting` so that is the library we
will use.

```
Require Import Sorting ZArith.
```

Now if I type `Search StronglySorted.`  I see there is a new theorem added to the results, with the name `NatSort.StronglySorted_sort`.  The plot thickens.  The statement of this theorem is long, but it basically expresses that if the relation computed by the function `Nat.leb` is transitive, then the function `NatSort.sort` indeed returns a sorted list.

Well, we do not want a sorting function on natural numbers, but a sorting function on integers of type `Z`.  But if you study the file `Mergesort.v` you see that `NatSort` is an instantiation of a *functor* on a structure that describes the comparison function for natural numbers and the proof that this comparison is *total* in a certain senses.  So we only need to create the same kind of structure for integers.

Please note that the statement I proved for the lemma `exists_sorted` is not the same as the one you used.  The important modification is that the order of existential statements and universal quantifications are not the same.  With your statement, one could prove the statement by providing only a list containing a or not, depending on whether a is in L or not.

Now, this is only a partially satisfactory answer, because `StronglySorted (fun x y => (x <=? y)%Z)` is not the same as your `sorted`.  This shows us that there is a missing lemma in the library expressing `StronglySorted R1 <-> StronglySorted R2` when `R1` and `R2` are equivalent.

Complement: to have the statement with the right relation in `StronglySorted` you would need something close to the following proof.  Lemma `StronglySorted_impl` should be provided in module `Sorted` too, in my opinion.

```
Lemma StronglySorted_impl {A : Type} (R1 R2 : A -> A -> Prop) (l : list A) :
  (forall x y, List.In x l -> List.In y l -> R1 x y -> R2 x y) ->
  StronglySorted R1 l -> StronglySorted R2 l.
Proof.
intros imp sl; revert imp; induction sl as [ | a l sl IHsl Fl];
  intros imp; constructor.
  now apply IHsl; intros x y xin yin; apply imp; simpl; right.
clear IHsl sl; revert imp; induction Fl; auto.
constructor;[now apply imp; simpl; auto | ].
apply IHFl.
intros y z yin zin; apply imp; simpl in yin, zin.
  now destruct yin as [ ya | yin]; simpl; auto.
now destruct zin as [za | zin]; simpl; auto.
Qed.

Lemma exists_sorted':  forall (L : list Z), exists L0 : list Z, 
 StronglySorted (fun x y => (x <= y)%Z) L0 /\ 
 (forall a: Z, List.In a L <-> List.In a L0).
Proof.
intros L; destruct (exists_sorted L) as [L' [sl permP]].
exists L'; split; [ | exact permP].
apply (StronglySorted_impl (fun x y => is_true (x <=? y)%Z)); auto.
now intros x y _ _; apply Zle_bool_imp_le.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually picking the order is not so trivial in constructive type theory, if you allow `Z` to be any type. I recommend you have a look to Cyril's Cohen (and others) [`finmap` library](https://github.com/math-comp/finmap) , in particular, given a type `T` with a choice principle and decidable equality it exactly does what you want, that is to say, to derive a canonical ordering for any list of `T`.

In particular, see the sorting function [here](https://github.com/math-comp/finmap/blob/4f988cfc7df7cf929bb1168985a7c0756ee79456/finmap.v#L342)

```
Definition f (s : seq K) := choose (perm_eq (undup s)) (undup s).
```

where

```
choose : forall T : choiceType, pred T -> T -> T
```

is the choice principle, `undup` removes duplicates, and `perm_eq` equality up to permutation.

**Edit** for the case of a type that already has an equality relation the proof should be trivial provided you have a sort function and its theory of course. Example:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Open Scope ring_scope.
Import Num.Theory.

Lemma exists_sorted (N : realDomainType) (l : seq N) :
  exists l_sorted, sorted <=%R l_sorted /\ perm_eq l_sorted l.
Proof.
exists (sort <=%R l).
by split; [apply: (sort_sorted (@ler_total _))|apply/perm_eqlP/perm_sort].
Qed.

Definition exists_sorted_int := exists_sorted [realDomainType of int].
```

In fact, the whole theorem is redundant as you are better off with the primitive theory.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I should clarify that by "Z" I meant integers, which probably makes this a little more trivial.

Comment: Oh, for integers the theorem is trivial then, just call a sort function.